# What is Android TABLET file structure?

Tags: android, file-structure

I am an Android newb, Linux "expert" :)
I have downloaded a book to my tablet (NO SD Card) from my "calibre" server across my local network. The Browser App finds this book in "Documents". However, my PDF reader app does not seem able to find "Documents" offering instead a root based directory structure to navigate.
Using the Shell Terminal Emulator App I cannot use 'find' (find: not found), I cannot figure out how to use 'ls' (ls: Unknown option "-h". Aborting)
Searching the web finds lots of tutorials on how to get started or how to build apps, but nothing in between - that I can find.

Can you tell me where to find "Documents" in the root based file structure? 
Can you point me to a tutorial (or two) which might cover these elementary topics (file structure, CLI usage) without delving into app-building (not yet anyway...)?
Thanks.

Comment: Since this question doesn't appear to be about programming, it may be better suited to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your input Ellis ... I cannot start programming without this information ...

Comment: You may find that you get an answer more quickly on Android Enthusiasts, that's all I meant.

Comment: Thanks, Ellis. Finally got it posted today on Android Enthusiasts. As you suggested, it got no responses here :)